# jquery element to javascript element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

So I am working with css animations, and in javascript you can start one and stop one with the following code:

```
element.style.webkitAnimationPlayState="paused";
element.style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";
```

now I have some Jquery that looks as such:

```
$(".info").click(function(){
    $it = $(this).closest(".thing");
    //how can I use the above javascript on the specified jquery element?
});
```

my question is in the comment in the code. **Is this possible? and how?**

[here is a jsfiddle showing how it is not working](http://jsfiddle.net/zj5G5/)

Answer (score 3):

here `$lt` is a jQuery wrapper object, not a dom element reference, you can get the dom element reference using the index 0

```
$it[0].style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KZQbL/)

or use the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) provided by jQuery to set the style value

```
$it.css('webkitAnimationPlayState', 'running');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aB6mc/)

Comment: thanks...now look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zj5G5/11/ ... how come the pause doesn't work?

Comment: @RyanSaxe it should be like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8WQcy/1/ the `on` method should be called in the wrapper element... also it should not be inside the click handler...

Comment: the jsfiddle you gave me does not work...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pause an animation (and then resume from the point that it was paused) you could toggle it's play state with this CSS property:

```
.paused {
   -ms-animation-play-state:paused;
   -o-animation-play-state:paused;
   -moz-animation-play-state:paused;
   -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

You could then use jquery to toggle the paused class:

```
$(".info").click(function(){
    $it = $(this).closest(".thing");
    $it.toggleClass("paused");
});
```

Comment: i'm not trying to pause an animation...

Answer (score 0):

$it is an array. So if it contains only one element, you can do,

```
$it[0].style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";
```

and if $it contains more than one element and you want to apply this style to each element then,

```
$($it).each(function(){this.style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [CSS property of jquery](http://api.jquery.com/css/) element to do this.

```
$(".info").click(function(){
    var $it = $(this).closest(".thing");
    alert($it.text());
    $it.css({"webkitAnimationPlayState":"running"}); 
});
```

[DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/sudhAnsu63/zj5G5/9/)